# Is glDebugMessageCallbackKHR implemented in Android 6?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-extensions

I am trying to implement the OpenGL function for debug callbacks added with the Android [OpenGL ES 3.1 extension pack](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/ANDROID/ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a.txt) in Android 5.0.
When I try to setup a callback: `GLES31Ext.glDebugMessageCallbackKHR(myCallback);`
it throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: not yet implemented`. 
This is on a Sony Xperia Z5 running Android 6.0, querying OpenGL context version returns OpenGL ES 3.1. Querying the list of supported OpenGL extensions returns that the extension `GL_KHR_debug` is avaialble (which this function is a part of).

Googling returned no useful results, my only hint is this file in the Android source repo: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/android-6.0.1_r63/opengl/tools/glgen/stubs/gles11/glDebugMessageCallbackKHR.cpp

Does this mean Google has not implemented this function although my device reports that this functionality is supported? Or this is just an issue with my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension string is simply reported from the underlying OpenGL ES driver, so the functionality should be available via NDK code. It does look like it's missing from the Java bindings though.

Comment: Yeah, as I see implementing this would be more than a simple call to the openGL driver on Google's side. But Google was sloppy and did not implement it. On the plus side the code is there for Android N.

Comment: Is it? I just tried using the 'glDebugMessageCallbackKHR' on a Nexus 5X with Android 8.1.0 updated today, still 'not yet implemented'